# Writing a Left-to-right text inside a Right-to-left (and vice versa) sentences or pragraphs

Tags: tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE in Right-to-left mode. sometime i need to right an specific word or text with Left-to-right direction inside a paragraph or a long sentences.

A common example is writing a phone number inside a text:

```
لطفا با شماره تلفن +1 818 574 3696 تماس بگیرید
```

Is this example only phone number should be Left-to-right to be shown correctly as `+1 818 574 3696`.

I'm wonder if there is way to do that in TinyMCE without editing the HTML code manually.

Comment: looks like you will have to type the phone number the other way around then